# MySQL Select only returning one row from eclipse

Tags: mysql, sql, eclipse, select, row

Im using eclipse with the mysql library, i am trying to get a list of products from the database(there are only two), and it only return the first row.
Why does the query only return one row? i think it might be something to do with wrong imports, i have no idea, im lost.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;


import classes.Product;

public class ProductDAO {

public ArrayList<Product> getProducts(){
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet;
    PreparedStatement statement;
    ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList();
    Connect con = new Connect();

    try{
        connection = con.connectTo();
        statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY sales DESC;");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        if(resultSet.next()){
            Product product = new Product();
            product.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            product.setMake(resultSet.getString("make"));
            product.setPrice(resultSet.getInt("price"));
            product.setDescription(resultSet.getString("description"));
            product.setCategory(resultSet.getString("category"));
            product.setSales(resultSet.getInt("sales"));
            product.setImage(resultSet.getString("image"));
            products.add(product);
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex);
    }


    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change:

```
if(resultSet.next()){
```

to

```
while(resultSet.next()){
```

resultSet.next() moves to the next row of data so you can then read it. It also returns true if there was a row or false if there wasn't.

Currently your code is just asking the resultset to get the first or or do nothing, whereas using the while will create a loop which will run until there are no more rows left. (or not run at all if there was none).

Comment: Please don't! If everybody who made this error did that, there'd be no SQL developers left. :-)

Comment: @Gary-Perry Don't worry about it, happens to the best of us.... Although the mistake I usually make is not actually adding each product to the products list! Causes the same result though :-)